# Flutter Firestore\ How to get field value from map under array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlk41.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzduW.jpg)

I develop an application by using Flutter and firestore. But now I having trouble,
I don't know how to get the field value(underlined in red),I have read the Firebase Documentation but it's still confused me.

My English is pretty limited,please forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firestore, you first read the entire document, and then get the fields you want on the client (in this case Flutter).

For example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('playroom')
.get()
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc["Material_List"][0]["X1"]);
    });
});
```

This prints all of the first "X1" values in the playroom collection.

If you want a specific document, do this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('playroom')
.doc("ID OF THE DOCUMENT")
.get()
.then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  print(doc.data()["Material_List"][0]["X1"]);
});
```

Comment: I am a Novice programmer, it's difficult to start. Thanks you so much!

Comment: This answer isn't applicable to Flutter SDK.